# TV Show from 90s where a woman uses VR Glasses and is chased by a man

Tags: tv, story-identification

I'm looking for a TV show from the 90s (I think), where a woman puts on glasses and uses these glasses and a computer to go into an alternative/parallel universe where she is chased by some man. I think it is an American show.

Comment: When she went into the alt/parallel universe, was it a CG or any sort of 3D world? Was there any sort of visual effect to differentiate the two?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't remember.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This sounds like my vague memories of [VR.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VR5).  I believe the protagonist was being chased/stalked by some malevolent person in the VR world.  Do you recall if phones were used to enter the "alternative/parallel universe"?  That was a key element in entering the surreal Virtual Reality in VR.5.

Comment: I think Keen is right.  That was my first thought as well.

Comment: Yes, its been bugging me for some time now! Thank you!

Answer (score -6):

The TV Show's name is Parallel Universe.
Refference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_Universe_(Red_Dwarf)

Comment: Huh? That's an *episode* in a TV show, that is nothing like what the OP describes.